# Can not read env varible in nuxtjs?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using nuxtjs 3, i'm trying to setup an axios instance so i create a file in .\plugins folder, then i put my config file in another folder, this file export an object which i will use to create my axios instance. I setup like this because sometime in the future i can reuse it. In my plugin i tried to create an axios instance, but i realize that i got undefined baseUrl.

I'm trying to setup an nuxtjs 3 base code for my project. Can you suggest me any public git repo example for it

config

```js
export default {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
}
```

```js
import axios from "axios";
import config from "@/config/axios-config.js";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            hello: () => {
                const instance = axios.create(config);
                console.log(config);
                return instance;
            },
        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want use `.env` variables in nuxt 3 app you need to do that:

1. Install `@nuxtjs/dotenv` via npm or yarn

```
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/dotenv
```

2. Open the `nuxt.config.js` file in your project's root directory and add the following code:

```
export default {
  // Other Nuxt 3 configuration options

  vite: {
    plugins: [
      require('dotenv').config()
    ]
  }
};
```

3. Now you can use `.env` variables in any component or js files:

Using in template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>API Base URL: {{ $env.API_BASE_URL }}</p>
    <p>API Key: {{ $env.API_KEY }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Using in script:

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('API Base URL:', this.$env.API_BASE_URL);
    console.log('API Key:', this.$env.API_KEY);
  }
};
</script>
```

More info about `@nuxtjs/dotenv` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny one, I had a similar issue and found I was having to do the following with Vite that might apply to what NuxtJS uses under its hood too?

Use `process.env.BASE_URL` in configs, basically any files involved with the build or server service runtimes.

Use `import.meta.env.BASE_URL` when in actual App project code.